# read blob data extra argument bytes in call swift

Tags: sqlite, swift, blob, nsdata

I am trying to read blob data from sqlite, but I get `Extra argument 'bytes' in call` error.

Here is my code:

```
var len = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 0)
var point = sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 0)
var dbData:NSData? = NSData(bytes: point, length: len)// ERROR: Extra argument 'bytes' in call

if dbData != nil
{
   arrDataRow.addObject(dbData!)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_bytes` returns an `Int32`, but 
`NSData(bytes:, length: )` expects an `Int` as second argument,
therefore you have to convert the value explicitly:

```
let dbData = NSData(bytes: point, length: Int(len))
```

Note also that this `NSData` initializer does *not* return an optional,
so assigning it to an `var dbData:NSData?` makes not much sense,
and even then `dbData` will never be `nil`.

What you can do
is to check if `sqlite3_column_blob()` returned `nil` or not:

```
let len = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 0)
let point = sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 0)
if point != nil {
    let dbData = NSData(bytes: point, length: Int(len))
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in Swift 4.2

```
if let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(albumQueryPointer, 0){
    let dataBlobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(albumQueryPointer, 0)
    let data = Data(bytes: dataBlob, count: Int(dataBlobLength))
}
```